# MS Teams Connector Save Button Gives Error: Received error from connectors

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I am getting "Unable to save connector configuration. Please try again." error when I try to save my connector on MS Teams.

Error details are below:

```
Received error from connectors
{
    "seq": 1623959414107,
    "timestamp": 1623959424578,
    "flightSettings": {
        "Name": "ConnectorFrontEndSettings",
        "AriaSDKToken": "d127f72a3abd41c9b9dd94faca947689-d58285e6-3a68-4cab-a458-37b9d9761d35-7033",
        "SPAEnabled": true,
        "ClassificationFilterEnabled": true,
        "ClientRoutingEnabled": true,
        "EnableYammerGroupOption": true,
        "EnableFadeMessage": false,
        "EnableDomainBasedOwaConnectorList": false,
        "EnableDomainBasedTeamsConnectorList": false,
        "DevPortalSPAEnabled": true,
        "ShowHomeNavigationButtonOnConfigurationPage": false,
        "DisableConnectToO365InlineDeleteFeedbackPage": true
    },
    "status": 500,
    "clientType": "SkypeSpaces",
    "connectorType": "9891a151-05c2-4c8d-9064-aba9d928cf94",
    "name": "handleMessageError"
}
```

I couldn't figure out the source of the problem. Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Yavuz - Could you please share the manifest here?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue.

I used this tutorial provided by MS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msteams-webhooks-connectors/7-exercise-o365-connectors

Don't use it.

Instead use this sample: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/connector-generic/nodejs